# Bandwidth limit for FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Currently, using FFmpeg to push a live TV stream to TVHeadend.

The stream is currently in 1080p. Is there a way to get FFmpeg to convert it to 720p for TVHeadend?

Comment: Do you want to limit the bandwidth, or do you want 720p? Not sure what you want to do here.

Comment: Can you show the FFmpeg command you're currently using? You'd have to limit bitrate and resolution to conserve bandwidth.